# Permitir somente números inteiros em uma coluna da JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Abaixo tenho um modelo de `Jtable`. Existe somente uma coluna editável para número (segundos). Como validar para que aceite somente números inteiros, e no caso do usuário digitar qualquer outra coisa, exceto número inteiro, retorne ZERO?

```
public class Tabela_Fluxograma extends AbstractTableModel {
private ArrayList linhas = null;
private String[] colunas = null;

public Tabela_Fluxograma (ArrayList lin, String[] col){
    setLinhas(lin);
    setColunas(col);    
}

public ArrayList getLinhas() {
    return linhas;
}

public void setLinhas(ArrayList dados) {
    this.linhas = dados;
}

public String[] getColunas() {
    return colunas;
}

public void setColunas(String[] nome) {
    this.colunas = nome;
}

public int getColumnCount(){
    return colunas.length;
}

public int getRowCount (){
    return linhas.size();
}

public String getColumnName (int numCol){
    return colunas[numCol];
}

public Object getValueAt (int numLin, int numCol){
    Object[] linha = (Object[])getLinhas().get(numLin);
    return linha[numCol];
}

@Override
public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
return column == 3;
}

@Override
public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    Object[] linha = (Object[]) getLinhas().get(rowIndex);
    linha[columnIndex] = aValue;
    //este método é quem notifica a mudança do model na tabela
    fireTableDataChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A forma correta de restringir isso é através do método [`getColumnClass`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html#getColumnClass-int-) que seu TableModel herda da `AbstractTableModel`:

```
public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) { 
    return columnIdex == 3 ? Integer.class : super.getColumnClass(columnIndex);
}
```

Dessa forma ai não vai permitir que se salve nenhum valor que não seja do tipo `Integer` nesta coluna, sendo necessário ou deixar em branco ou preencher corretamente para que se permita a conclusão da edição da célula nesta coluna.

Apenas para exemplificar o que vai ocorrer, veja o gif abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia. Conforme comentou Articuno, precisei mudar pra não permitir texto ou retornar zero, embora seja bem útil sua sugestão. Obrigado pelas sugestões. Só pra concluir vou colocar o trecho final do tablemodel. Passo o valor para outro método, valida e retorna.

```
@Override
public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    Object[] linha = (Object[]) getLinhas().get(rowIndex);
    int valor = validateInt(aValue);
    linha[columnIndex] = valor;
    fireTableDataChanged();
}

private int validateInt(Object numberObj){
    try {
        int number = Integer.parseInt((String) numberObj);
        return number; 
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return 0;
}
}
```

Comment: Acho que da pra simplificar: `linha[columnIndex] = validateInt(aValue);`

Comment: Isso mesmo.. rsrs.. Obrigado

Comment: Não entendi, se fez dessa forma, o getcolumnclass não se faz necessário.

Comment: Alias, o método `getColumnClass` não vai deixar passar nada que não possa ser convertido pra integer para o `setValueAt`. Você não usou este método?

Comment: Não usei o método. Não estava "produtivo" aqui a exibição de texto. Foi necessário zerar imediatamente. O valor digitado vai direto para o banco de dados.

Comment: Como assim produtivo? Minha sugestão não deixa o setvalueat ser chamado até que a conversão implicita do tipo da coluna esteja correto. Então seu código da pergunta não está completo. Minha sugestão foi com base nele, mas se você não apresenta tudo que é necessario na pergunta, pode acontecer isso.

Comment: Então, foi um equívoco meu. Como sou iniciante em java achei que não seria necessário apresentar. Mas foi útil também para outro table model que eu tenho. As duas sugestões me ajudou.

Comment: **Sempre apresente um [mcve]**, dessa forma, evita que receba respostas que estejam incompletas ou que nem a atendam seu problema.

Answer (score -1):

Usando cast de `Int` você consegue fazer esta validação:

```
private int validateInt(float number){
if(number == (int)number)
   return number;
else
   return 0
}
```

Comment: E como ele vai aplicar isso na tabela? Além disso não se aplicar a jtable, ainda vai estourar exceção.

Comment: Ele pediu uma função para validar entrada de numeros inteiros amigo

Comment: Entrada de inteiros **numa jtable**, portanto esse metodo não vai funcionar, nao desta forma. A forma correta é como respondi, utilizando a propria classe model que irá monitorar entrada de dados de acordo com o tipo. Outra coisa, a linha da tabela permite digitar qualquer coisa, se eu digito uma string, esse metodo seu ai vai travar a aplicaçao toda estourando uma exceção.

Comment: Obrigado pela colaboração de ambos.
O que queria mesmo foi o que o Articuno me sugeriu. Validar inteiro, na coluna 3 e numa jTable. Acabei de complementar o código aqui e ficou como esperado. Obrigado

Comment: @rafB o problema é que esse método com certeza vai estourar exceção se você aplicar no seu Model, e vai travar a tabela, por isso questionei o autor. Em modo texto, talvez seja funcional, pra JTable esse método não funcionaria.